# What does "why" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

What is the meaning and usage of *why* in the sentence below:

> All my aunts and uncles talked it over as if they were choosing a prep-school for me and finally said, ‘**Why**—yees’ with very grave, hesitant faces.

Is it a form of confirmation and agreement? Is it equal to *yes*?

In what kind of prose is it used? Is it archaic or contemporary?

Answer (score 5):

**Why** in this sense is

> —used to express mild surprise, hesitation, approval, disapproval, or
>   impatience "why, here's what I was looking for" - *[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/why)*>

It is old-fashioned, yes. But people say this sort of word  without thinking, and can be surprised to find they still use it. My neice only realised she said "blimey" a lot when she went to the US. She thought she'd never use such an old (to her) expression.

Answer (score -1):

**Why-yes** means **of course**. I'm looking for a dictionary reference and will insert as soon as I find.